# Using Poltergiest to give user of app a screenshot of their page

Tags: poltergeist

Does anyone know if this can be done?

I have used Poltergeist on other websites and in a testing framework.

Is it possible to have a controller and class that will deliver to the user a screenshot of the page of the app they're logged into?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No

Longer answer:
  Poltergeist uses the headless phantomjs "browser" for the rendering of the pages it visits.  It can't connect to or be installed to random users browsers, so there's no way for it take a screen shot of a users browser.

Comment: OK to put it another way, in order to get a screenshot of my application's Users#Show page, let's say, Capybara would have to log in as the user, navigate to the page and save screenshot? There is no way to save a screenshot of that user's page "internally" from the Rails app?